# I need to insert text before and after an existing text file

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a list of 10 digit numbers in a text file, I need to insert a line of code before and after the number.

EX.

```
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>508805***5</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
```

I havent found a fast way to do this but I think I can use a simple batch file or sql.

my text file looks like this

```
5088055401
5088039781
5088046588
5104231304
5088054110
5104004855
5088048942
5088050328
5104224271
```

I need the output file to look like this

```
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088053248</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055611</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088053981</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055624</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055660</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055661</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088053558</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055805</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055888</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088047155</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088055639</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088053265</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>2896246920</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088037383</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088039562</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>
```

I need to insert " before and "after.

Any help would be great,
Thanks

Comment: Post the code that you have tried

Comment: I haven't used any code mostly copy paste, trying to write a macro but its not working, I have an output file of numbers that is all.

Comment: If you "insert **a line** of code before and after the number", then each _input line_ is converted into _three output lines_, right? Please, post the output you want from the input you provided... **`:(`**

Comment: `< NUL (for /F %%a in (input.txt) do set /P "=<CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>%%a</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>" & echo/) > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with powershell, then you can use below code

```
$PreviousLine = "Previous Line"
$NextLine = "Next Line"
$InputFile = "C:\input.txt"
$OutputFile= "C:\output.txt"
foreach($line in Get-Content $InputFile)
    {
    if($line -match $regex)
        {
                Add-Content $OutputFile ($line -replace $line, ($PreviousLine+ $line+ $NextLine))
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need it look more like this,    <CRsiRemoveUser><UserID>5088052965</UserID></CRsiRemoveUser>

Comment: Updated the answer. Just change the values of previous line and next line.

Comment: I am getting an error when I run the code, I guess I am new to this. Is there some documentation that goes over how to run it? I have tried to run it windows, cmd command.

Comment: open CMD in windows, copy script, paste script into CMD window and hit enter. I may be doing it wrong